# Why could not the doctor just shoot John Wick in part 3 and get the reward?

Tags: plot-explanation, john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum

Here is the thing: when I first saw the Asian doctor pull out a gun, I thought he would just kill him and receive his reward.

Why could not he just kill John Wick? Of course the movie would end.. and then its a very short movie, but still - is not it logical?

[image]

[doctor and john wick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkO9e.jpg)

Comment: That assumes the doctor was interested in collecting the reward, perhaps he wasn't?

Comment: Because he was the key maker from The Matrix. :D

Comment: The term "Hippocratic Oath" comes to mind...

Comment: Perhaps he was thinking about all those other people who thought they had the drop on John Wick, many of them trained killers at the peak of their physical abilities, and how they ended up and reconsidered his chances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well for starters, when John first arrives he still has time left till hes a target. Its made quite clear just before this that you are not supposed to target him before the kill order is finalized.
When he is attacked in the Library by the big guy, presumably the guy would not have been able to claim the bounty or would have been excommunicated also.

As for why the doctor doesn't shoot him after the time is up and John is still there, well that's most likely because the doctor has morals and a code of honor that is a present theme in the movie. He is also quite clearly not an active assassin either so does not actively target people anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Eh? He didn't want to.

The doctor was a friend of John. Didn't want to kill him, so why would he shoot him?

I dont think he ever got the idea of trying. Just as he did, the doctor only took out the gun so John could use it and fake the whole thing was forced.